# SQL SELECT STEPS FROM A STRING

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLI5i.png)I am currently facing a problem :
This is my column **Steps**

`Eat ; Sleep ; Gym ; Work`

All this name have a specific number like step `1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4`
**The problem is that** some times i have rows where there are not only **4** steps `1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 .... ; 12`

*Example of what i want in code (I would accept any other suggestion) :*

Count(String beetween ";")
I though about using (Substring and count) to know how many ";"

While < Steps string

then substring,col1,1 is step 1 but i dont want the string i just want to tell that this position is STEP 1 in my table "STEPS" .. do until the while condition is done.
I already know how to get the row:
`DECLARE @i int = 0
WHILE @i < SELECT LEN(actions) - LEN(REPLACE(actions, ';', ''))
BEGIN`
   `select DISTINCT substring_index(substring_index(actions, ';', 1), ';', -1)
from persons` 
I dont know how to mark all those gotten "Lines as 1 in my new column *steps*

`SET @i = @i + 1` 
`END`

But i want that this step will be marked with 1 in another table :

Comment: What exactly is your expected output here?

Comment: I expect , to know the best way to fix my problem 
Like : 
example 
I want in my column Steps(Int)
when i seek for 1 i get Eat
i seek for 2 i get Sleep and eat and sleep are all action in my column "actions": Eat;Sleep;Gym;Work for each persson, That's why its always changing

Comment: my suggestion is to normalize this properly before going further.  you need a structure that can be queried readily

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I updated some how what i want , sorry for the problem

Comment: This is what i am exactly trying to get help about https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLI5i.png

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?
This is how I would do it in SQL Server if I understand what you are looking for correctly:

```
declare @string varchar(max)='Eat ; Sleep ; Gym ; Work'
declare @string2 varchar(max)=''
declare @table table (rowid int identity, value varchar(max))
set @string=@string+';'
while @string<>''
begin
select @string2=left(@string, charindex(';', @string))
insert @table 
select ltrim(replace(@string2,';',''))
select @string = replace(@string, @string2,'') 
end 
select * from @table
```

Comment: Hello , I just added an image that will explain you exactly what i am seeking for and sorry that i mis explained my self https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLI5i.png